# HttpUrlConnection not showing exception thrown by called java program

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, httpurlconnection

I am having service throwing RuntimeException which working fine with ajax Call. If i call that service using HttpUrlConnection from another java program exception string not getting instead its showing 'Internal Server Error' with response code 500.

```
@Path("poService")
public class PoService {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @GET
    @Path("getPo/{poNo}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getPo(@PathParam("poNo") int poNo ) throws Exception{
       String urlStr = AppConstant.WEBOLIS_PATH + "po.htm?getPoForSrnConsReport=true&pono="+poNo ;
       URL url = new URL(urlStr);
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", AppConstant.USER_AGENT);
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
       System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
       System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
       System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseMessage());

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;
       StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
       }
       in.close();

       if( responseCode!=200 ){ // if any Error
         //throw new WebolisApiException( responseCode,  response.toString());
       }else{
       }
       return Response.ok( response.toString(),   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }


}
```

This is above REST method from which I am calling to another java Spring Controller.

```
 @RequestMapping( value="/po", method=RequestMethod.GET,params=  {"getPoForSrnConsReport"})  //,consumes="application/json" 
        @ResponseBody ModelMap getPoForSrnConsReport(HttpServletResponse response,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "pono" )   Integer poNo) throws Exception {
            ModelMap m = new ModelMap();
            PoService poService = new PoService();
            Po po = poService.getPo(poNo, poService.ALL_ITEMS , Boolean.FALSE);
            m.addAttribute("po",po);
            return m;
       }
```

in PoService i am throwing Custom Exception  'PO not Found' This string is not available in REST method

Comment: Well you're ignoring response codes other than 200. What exactly did you expect? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to open a connection to a server that sends an error code will throw an exception, that you need to catch. Also you cannot use `getInputStream()` when you get an error response code. You need to use `getErrorStream()`:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
}
catch(IOException e) {
    // handle specific exceptions here
}

int responseCode = -1;
try {
    responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    // handle specific exceptions here
}

// override the input if you got an error and an error stream is available
if (in==null && responseCode!=200 && con.getErrorStream() != null) {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
}
```

Comment: Thnx Max let me try using con.getErrorStrem().